# Fader/Hardie BG/NBD model. Interpretation of $a$ and $b$ of the beta distribution drop out process

Tags: beta-distribution, customer-lifetime-value

[On R's CLVTools package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CLVTools/vignettes/CLVTools.pdf), there's a sentence referring to the pareto/NBD model

I'm working with the BG/NBD model not the pareto/NBD model. I'd like to understand if I can interpret the parameters of this model in a similar way to the documentation on the pareto/NBD model.

From that link above on the Pareto/NBD model:

> For the standardPareto/NBD model, we get 4 parameters , ,  and
> . where ,  represent the shape and scale parameterof the gamma
> distribution that determines the purchase rate and ,  of the
> attrition rate across individualcustomers. / can be interpreted as
> the mean purchase and / as the mean attrition rate

The BG/NBD model I'm working with also returns 4 parameters:

- r: shape parameter of the Gamma distribution of the purchase process.
- alpha: scale parameter of the Gamma distribution of the purchase
  process.
- a: shape parameter of the Beta distribution of the dropout
  process.
- b: shape parameter of the Beta distribution of the dropout
  process.

The first two of these, , , are the same as for the Pareto/NBD model. So I'm assuming that I can interpret those two in the same way? "/ can be interpreted as the mean purchase (rate)"?

My question is about the remaining two parameters of the BG/NBD model, a and b. Can I calculate the mean attrition rate in a similar manner by dividing one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BG/NBD, individual attrition is defined by "p", which follows a beta distribution. The mean of the beta distribution is a/(a+b).  Hope this help.  BG/NBD was created by Fader, Hardie, and Lee.  Please attribute the credit correctly in the future.